# Getting Missing ) argument from below script any suggestions why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <form name="formone" id="optionsform">
    <fieldset>
    <label><input type="radio" name="group1" id="ac-yes" value="1">Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="group1" id="ac-no" value="0">No</label>

    <label><input type="radio" name="group2" id="bt-yes" value="2">Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="group2" id="bt-no" value="0">No</label>

    <a href="varible-address">CONTINUE</a>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      var urls = new Array();
      urls[0]='http://myurl1/';// no + no
      urls[1]='http://myurl2/';// yes + no
      urls[2]='http://myurl3/';// no + yes
      urls[3]='http://myurl4/';// yes + yes

      $('input[type=radio]').click(fonction(){
        var score = 0;
        $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){score+=parseInt($(this).val()});
        $('a').attr('href',urls[score]);
      }
   });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
 $('input[type=radio]').click(fonction(){
    var score = 0;
    $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){score+=parseInt($(this).val()});
    $('a').attr('href',urls[score]);
  }
```

To

```
  $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){ // 'function' not fonction
    var score = 0;
    $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){score+=parseInt($(this).val()); /* missed ');' here */ });
    $('a').attr('href',urls[score]);
  }); // <-- see the closing ');' here
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
  $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
        var score = 0;
        $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){score+=parseInt($(this).val()});
        $('a').attr('href',urls[score]);
  });
```

Comment: Nope there's actually another missing ); on line 3

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing parenthesis for the `.click(` call. You also have `function` mispelled there.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelt `function`, so while you are trying to pass a function statement, you are actually passing a function call followed by a block where a block isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){score+=parseInt($(this).val()});
```

The Above line is Missing the ')' Symbol after ParseInt in your code

```
$('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){score+=parseInt($(this).val())});
```